# Creating an executable from a python GUI using py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a .py file that creates a GUI, which runs another script once I give it some information. I'm trying to make a .exe file from this GUI file using py2exe, but I've been having trouble.

```
Exception: Seems not to be an exe-file
```

If anyone who has experience with py2exe and has encountered this message before, could you explain to me why it's not working, and what I could do to fix it? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My setup.py looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['test_gui.py'])
```

I run this code through the command prompt like this:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

And the traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup(console=['test_gui.py'])
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 305, in _run
    dlls = self.find_dlls(extensions)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 389, in find_dlls
    self.dll_excludes)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1064, in find_d
    ependend_dlls
    bin_depends(loadpath, images + [sys.executable], excludes_use)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1441, in bin_de
    pends
    if isSystemDLL(dll):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1498, in isSyst
    emDLL
    raise Exception, "Seems not to be an exe-file"
Exception: Seems not to be an exe-file
```

Comment: You have to show us more information. What does your setup.py look like? How are you running py2exe? Where do you get that exception, and what's the traceback (if any). Otherwise, the only advice anyone can give you is to work through the examples in the tutorial and make sure they work on your system and you understand what they're doing.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for specifying the information I needed to give!

Comment: OK, it looks like somehow `py2exe` is picking up a dependency on some DLL that isn't actually a DLL. Presumably it's either got the wrong path for Python26.dll, or for something _it_ depends on, or the same is true for a C extension module (.dll/.pyd/.so) that you're directly or indirectly importing. The first step is to get debugging information about which DLL it's complaining about, and the first step to that (as explained in the [FAQ](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ)) is `python -m py2exe.mf -d path/to/test_gui.py`.

Comment: Also, just passing `-d` (or multiple `-d` levels) to your main command might be enough to show you where it's going wrong. If neither of those helps, you may have to hack up `py2exe` to dump information on what `dll` is and why it chose to look at it.

Comment: @abarnert I'm pretty new to this, so I'm not exactly sure what I need to do. I saved the output of that command into a txt file, and I see that there's a list of missing modules in the form of `? _emx_link imported from os`. If I import the os module will that resolve the error?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. If you don't understand the output of the two debug runs, you may want to upload them as a gist/pastebin/whatever and post a link here, so others can look through them. It will be difficult for anyone to debug your problem without that information.

Comment: Here's the log: [link](http://pastebin.com/zhxmn3H9). I tried looking at this, but I couldn't really figure it out, so thanks in advance.

Comment: The debug output for the actual `py2exe` line is also useful. But there's some good stuff here. Forget everything before the table starting at line 234, but after that, each filename ending in `.pyd` is supposed to be a DLL (so are the ones with no filename—they're inside the standard library, so you can find them there if you want). There are a million ways to check each one. Do you know how to use `ctypes` from within Python to open and inspect a DLL? If not, can you search for, download, and run `TrID` against each one and make sure it's a "Win32 Dynamic Link Library"?

Comment: @abarnert Sorry for the late response; I had to leave for the rest of the day. I tried TrID against each .pyd file like you said, but they all report "Python Dynamic module" with a probability of around 63% (although I'm not sure if this is supposed to be surprising).

Comment: That's not surprising, but it does rule out one possible problem. Again, you still need to get the debug output for the `py2exe` command that fails. I can't remember if that's `python setup.py py2exe -d` or something different, but it should be easy to figure out or find in the docs.

Comment: -d requires an argument, and I can't for the life of me find it in any documentation. I tried `python -d setup.py py2exe` as a wild guess, but ended up with the same traceback that was in the original post.

Comment: Attaching the `-d` to python itself will just turn on `PYTHONDEBUG=1` to show debug output from the interpreter's parse stage. Try `python setup.py p2exe --help`, or read the documentation; there are either options to turn up debugging/verbosity, or options to stop after each stage, but I can't remember which.

Comment: Or, again, run py2exe in a debugger, or just hack up your local copy—at `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py:1498`, instead of `raise Exception, "Seems not to be an exe-file"` do `raise Exception("'%s' seems not to be an exe-file" % (pathname,), pathname)`. Then, run your `python setup.py py2exe` again, and, when you get an error, it will tell you exactly which file has a problem.

Comment: py2exe is complaining about a few empty .dll files (msvcp90.dll, for example). What can I do to resolve this?